# Using MQL5 network functions on strategy tester

Tags: sockets, network-programming, mql, metatrader5

I want to receive data from metatrader and use them to do some process in another programming language, i can connect metatrader and my other script code with the network functions that mql5 has been provided but they don't work for testing on strategy tester panel 
is there any way to gain a permission or bypass that problem?

everything works fine when i add the expert to charts but for backtesting not work and when i want to create socket using `CreateSocket` function return a permission error (4014)

```
int socket = CreateSocket()
if(socket!=INVALID_HANDLE) {
     Print("Failed to create a socket, error ",GetLastError()); // return 4014 on backtesting
}
```

is there any way to allow metatrader to use network functions here?

Comment: faced the same issue, did you find any solution for this?